# How to update code on multiple workstations?

Tags: python, git, github

I made a code in python at home, and sent it to my school pc in the school to test it there. Is it possible to auto-update the code at school everytime i edit it at home? Keep in mind that I am a begginer.

Comment: Better configure a git repo on both systems so that you can pull and push on both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Version Control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) software like [git](https://git-scm.com/) to update your code to a `repository` (think of it as a folder accessible over internet with all your code) every time you change it, whether be it at home or school, and you can get the latest changes when you try to get them where-ever you want to/

There are great tutorials available online to begin with here: https://git-scm.com/doc, starting from the videos here: https://git-scm.com/videos which would give you a good background of things. Git is a good thing to learn since it is also used in large software companies as well to do what you are trying to achieve in your school project :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept @SasaCZ Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome SasaCZ!

This is more of a file-sync problem than a Python problem.
If you don't want to host your own server you can use Dropbox, Box or other file sync/backup tool.

Git is a version control system to keep track of what have changed between the edits, so you can roll back or even remove a specific edit several days ago without destroying the work after that.

One of the problem you will find when running Python is that Python load most files on startup. So if the files change after the boot you have to have some way to detect file-changes and reboot Python. There is solution to this, but you still have to think about how you want your software to behave.

Hope this help you a bit of the way.